# retrieve parameters.yml in javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony

Can i retrieve the global parameters in file javascript?

i have for example

```
twitter.app_secret: my_token
```

how can i retrieve it in file Javascript ?

for now i use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app_assoluto = '{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}';
    var consumer_key_twitter = '{{ twitter_app_id }}';
    var consumer_secret_twitter = '{{ twitter_app_secret }}';
    var access_token_twitter = '{{ twitter_access_token }}';
    var access_token_secret_twitter = '{{ twitter_token_secret }}';
    var facebook_app_id = '{{ facebook_app_id }}';
    var env = '{{ app.environment }}';
</script>
```

also parameters like {{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}

there is a better solution for retrieve this param??

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that you are use twig templates. So, you can make your parameters as twig [globals](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html#using-service-container-parameters) like that:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        key: "%your_value%"
```

And in your templates you have access to `key` via `{{ key }}`

UPDATE

If you are using jQuery, you can do that in this way:

```
# template.html.twig
<script>
    var params = params || {};
    $.extend(params, {
        twitterAppId: '{{ twitter_app_id }}'
    });
</script>
```

and in your JS file:

```
# script.js
(function() {
    params = params || {};
    twitterAppId = params.twitterAppId ||{};
)();
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: i use globals, twitter_app_id is a global var like 
twig:
 globals:
twitter_app_id: "%twitter.app.id%"

but if i want retrieve  {{twitter_app_id}} in javascript ?

Comment: I don't understand lats question. Could you explain me what's wrong?

Comment: sorry for my english. I can not retrieve the parameters directly from the javascript file, I have to use the tag <script> </ script> inside a twig